# serverPollTimeout configuration for HttpPollingDuplex

Tags: silverlight-4.0, duplex, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I am writing card game using **Silverlight** and **HttpPollingDuplex**.

I have 4 seperate http duplex services, which can be called from my game (silverlight client)

**1. ChatService**

**2. AuthService**

**3. LobbyService**

**4. GameService**

After I host the game under **IIS 7.5** I note with **Fiddler** that **Silverlight** client do polling requests sequentially, and my application become very slow, because for example for getting message from chat service client have to wait until other services polling will be finished. Than I changed **serverPollTimeout** for services to finish pollings faster, now my game works faster, but do continues requests to services sequentially. so the question is

Is it possible to create client proxy or configure client to do polling queries parallel in case of more than one polling service? and if not is changing serverPollTimeout good practice in my case? or what will be the best configuration for me?

Creating proxy and calling service methods in separate thread doesn't help :(

*Thanks a lot!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my workout if someone has the same problem

There is a limit to how many HTTP connections Silverlight can use in the browser, If all the services live on the same host://name:port, there should be only one onging polling connection to it, no matter how many services are hosted there.

I created sub domains for each service, which solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions is set created instance as a static property.